# Retrofit 2.0 library not working for file uploading in above V6.0 versions

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

In my App I have file uploading concept. I have to upload image or video or audio. when ever I upload the file it goes into on failure method. not uploaded into the server while selecting any type of file. In android V5.0 it takes image somes takes video files. More times it goes into on failure.

```
ApiConfig service = ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiConfig.class);
File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);
Log.d("File", String.valueOf(file));
uploadfile.setText(String.valueOf(file));
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);
String descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking";
RequestBody description = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), descriptionString);
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(body);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                                   Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        String  Image_Url=null;
        try {
            Image_Url=response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("serverResponse.getData() ", Image_Url);
        Validations.MyAlertBox(AddNewFile.this, "File Successfully Uploaded");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
       progressDialog.dismiss();
       Validations.MyAlertBox(AddNewFile.this, "File not Uploaded");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please add some error logs so that we can identify the issue

Comment: Please add logs so we can help, code seems correct.

Comment: Can you pass MediaType.parse("text/plain") for description.

Comment: `Log.d("File", String.valueOf(file));`. Please tell what is logged. But that is a pretty strange log statement. Better use `Log.d("File", file.getAbsolutePath());`.